# Extracting Matrix from List of Matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix

Say I have a list of 3 Matrices. 
How do I extract one of the matrices as a Matrix-Object, so I can further access it's elements with `mymatrix[i,j]` calls?

`mylist[i]` simply returns a List-Object with Matrix `i`.

I'm sure there has to be a simple solution, but I couldn't manage to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use double brackets: `mylist[[i]]` ....

From `?"[["` (emphasis added):

> Recursive (list-like) objects:
>
> Indexing by ‘[’ is similar to atomic vectors and selects **a list of
>        the specified element(s)**.
>
> Both ‘[[’ and ‘$’ select **a single element of the list**.  The main
>        difference is that ‘$’ does not allow computed indices,

Answer (score 3):

`mylist[[1]]` should return you the first matrix

`mylist[[3]]` should return you the third matrix

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate this you could simply run:

```
for (index in 1:length(mylist)){
    assign(paste0("matrix", index), mylist[[index]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```